# I am trying to play animation once with Model Viewer

Tags: gltf, model-viewer

I am trying to make a multiple actions GLB file to play each animation action once.

My first attempt is to use code, it successfully stops the initial animation after it is played. I update the attr animation-name with the second action name. It triggers play() however it won't stop after the animation is ended.

```
const modelViewer = document.querySelector('#home-model-2');

const playOnce = () => {
  modelViewer.removeEventListener('animation-finish', playOnce);
  modelViewer.pause();
  modelViewer.currentTime = 0;
};

const play = () => {
  modelViewer.play({ repetitions: 1 });
  modelViewer.addEventListener('animation-finish', playOnce);
};

const onAnimationNameChange = () => {
  play();
  
};

modelViewer.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Create a new MutationObserver instance
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'animation-name') {
        onAnimationNameChange();
      }
    }
  });

  // Start observing changes to the attributes of the modelViewer element
  observer.observe(modelViewer, { attributes: true });

  // Initial play
  play();
});
```

My second attempt

```
const modelViewer = document.querySelector('#home-model-2');

const playOnce = () => {
  modelViewer.removeEventListener('animation-finish', playOnce);
  modelViewer.pause();
  modelViewer.currentTime = 0;
};

const play = () => {
  modelViewer.play({ repetitions: 1 });
  modelViewer.addEventListener('animation-finish', playOnce);
};

const onAnimationNameChange = () => {
  modelViewer.removeEventListener('animation-finish', playOnce);
  play();
};

modelViewer.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'animation-name') {
        onAnimationNameChange();
      }
    }
  });

  observer.observe(modelViewer, { attributes: true });

  play();
});
```

This is the container

```
<model-viewer id="home-model-2" src="//xxx.glb" ar-status="not-presenting" touch-action="none" shadow-intensity="0.3" autoplay="" exposure="1" shadow-softness="1" camera-orbit="8.742deg 83.8deg 2.011m" field-of-view="30deg" camera-target="-0.4517m 0.39m 0.1061m" animation-name="s2">
</model-viewer>
```

I dont understand why modelViewer.play({ repetitions: 1 }); could not work after the attributes is changed
or Any better idea on how to make my code work in this case?

Thanks